# How to remove blank lines from a text file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to duplicate the original into a new file. In the new file I want the exact same things as the original BUT no blank lines.

Note: I looked at other posts and tried with no success.

**Currently:**

```
1  

2  

3
```

**How I want it to be: -- no blank lines**

```
1  
2  
3
```

Here is my code so far:

```
   inputFileName = "x.txt";
   outputFileName = "y.txt";

   inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName));
   outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputFileName));

   String lineOfText = inputFile.readLine();

   while(lineOfText != null)
   {
       if (lineOfText.isEmpty())
       {
        outputFile.print("null");
       }

       outputFile.println(lineOfText);
       lineOfText = inputFile.readLine();
   } 

   inputFile.close();
   outputFile.close();
}
```

Thank you for all who can possibly help. I assumed that `print("null")` would print out 'nothing' but it indeed prints out null, I do not know how to print out 'nothing'.

Comment: just change if condition like this and it may work.
if(lineOfText.trim().isEmpty())

Comment: Also don't write "null", just don't do anything if the line is empty after trimming

Comment: The way to "print nothing" is to _not execute a statement that prints anything_.

Comment: Please post complete example. We should be able to copy and paste your code, add the necessary imports, and compile and run it ourselves. Then show an example run and explain how the output differs from what you want.

Comment: p.s. When solving problems like this, I always find it helpful to turn off my computer and use a pen and paper to write the steps needed **in words**. I mostly ignore Java syntax and jargon except that I will use words like "if", "while", and "for" if they are a natural part of the description.

Comment: Again, please stop defacing your questions. The moderators have been notified.

Comment: To deface is to spoil. I am simply asking a question, no spoiling.

Comment: You are removing code after the question has been answered, reducing its benefits for other later visitors.

Comment: Oh, I never knew that was a rule, sorry. I thought it would be better shorter, will not do again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but this

```
while(lineOfText != null)
{
   if (lineOfText.isEmpty())
   {
    outputFile.print("null");
   }
   outputFile.println(lineOfText);
   lineOfText = inputFile.readLine();
}
```

shouldn't be writing `null` on empty lines. I think you wanted something like

```
while(lineOfText != null)
{
   if (!lineOfText.isEmpty())
   {
      outputFile.println(lineOfText);
   }
   lineOfText = inputFile.readLine();
}
```

**Also**, I suggest you use a [`try-with-resources` Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead of manually managing your `close`(s). It's probably a good idea to `trim` (as suggested in the comments) before your test, and you can simplify your *loop* and you should limit variable visibility. All together like,

```
String inputFileName = "x.txt";
String outputFileName = "y.txt";

try (BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName));
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputFileName))) {
    String lineOfText;
    while ((lineOfText = inputFile.readLine()) != null) {
        lineOfText = lineOfText.trim();
        if (!lineOfText.isEmpty()) {
            outputFile.println(lineOfText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Is there a way to remove the blank line which now occurs at the last line of the file? (this is the only blank line there is now)

Comment: @ChosenForWorlds Depending on your platform, the final EOL may be required and may not considered a blank line at the end. So to preserve platform independence, it's usually best to include that last EOL. Java will ignore it and not return a blank line at the end when you read back the file with readLine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip the `println` in case the line is empty:

```
while(lineOfText != null)
{
   if (!lineOfText.isEmpty()) {
       outputFile.println(lineOfText);
   }
   lineOfText = inputFile.readLine();
 }
```

Comment: if his lineOfText="            " like get this type of value than lineOfText.isEmpty() return false. So, I think you should add lineOfText .trim().isEmpty() .

Comment: @Darshit : sure, depends what the author calls blank. In such case it would be worth looking at apache StringUtils.isBlank() - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner file;
        PrintWriter writer;

        try {

            file = new Scanner(new File("src/data1.txt"));
            writer = new PrintWriter("src/data2.txt");

            while (file.hasNext()) {
                String line = file.nextLine();
                if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                    writer.write(line);
                    writer.write("\n");
                }
            }

            file.close();
            writer.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

Comment: "\n" is a platform-specific line ending